# Find rows of a dataframe that have same non-unique column values as a column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes- OK_df and Not_OK_df :

```
OK_df = pd.DataFrame({'type_id' : [1,2,3,3], 'count' : [2,7,2,5], 'unique_id' : ['1|2','2|7','3|2','3|5'], 'status' : ['OK','OK','OK','OK']})
Not_OK_df = pd.DataFrame({'type_id' : [1,3,5,6,3,3,3,1], 'count' : [1,1,1,1,3,4,6,3], 'col3' : [1,5,7,3,4,7,2,2], 'unique_id' : ['1|1','3|1','5|1','6|1','3|3','3|4','3|6','1|3'], 'status' : ['Not_OK','Not_OK','Not_OK','Not_OK','Not_OK','Not_OK','Not_OK','Not_OK']})
```

Ok_df:

```
       type_id  count unique_id status
0        1      2       1|2     OK
1        2      7       2|7     OK
2        3      2       3|2     OK
3        3      5       3|5     OK
```

Not_OK_df:

```
  type_id  count  col3 unique_id  status
0        1      1     1       1|1  Not_OK
1        3      1     5       3|1  Not_OK
2        5      1     7       5|1  Not_OK
3        6      1     3       6|1  Not_OK
4        3      3     4       3|3  Not_OK
5        3      4     7       3|4  Not_OK
6        3      6     2       3|6  Not_OK
7        1      3     2       1|3  Not_OK
```

where,

type_id : Non-unique id for corresponding type.

count : Number of counts from first time a type_id was seen.

unique_id : Combination of type_id and count : 'type_id|count'

col3 : Another column.

status : Has values - OK or Not_OK

For a row in Ok_df there is atleast one row in Not_OK_df with the same type_id with count value less than count value of OK_df row.

I want to find Not_OK_df rows that satisfy the above condition i.e.,

```
Not_OK_df['type_id'] == OK_df['type_id'] & Not_OK_df['count'] < OK_df['count']
```

- I tried using the above condition directly but got the following error :

`Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

- I can't set the matching type_id as index to retrieve rows since type_id isn't unique. I can't use unique_id as index to retrieve as it is unique to both the dataframes.

The expected output is :

```
   type_id  count  col3 unique_id  status
0        1      1     1       1|1  Not_OK
1        3      1     5       3|1  Not_OK
2        3      3     4       3|3  Not_OK
3        3      4     7       3|4  Not_OK
```

Note : It doesn't contain rows with unique_id : ['3|6','1|3'] since there's no row in OK_df that has `OK_df['count'] > not_OK_df['count']`.

How can I retrieve the required rows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your selection criteria is as follows:

- The row from `Not_ok_df` must have the same `type_id` as a row in `ok_df`
- The same row must have a `count` smaller than the maximum `count` from rows of the same `type_id` in `ok_df`

First create a dictionary for the maximum value of `count` for each unique `type_id`.

```
max_counts =OK_df.groupby('type_id').max()['count'].to_dict()
```

Then check if every row in `Not_ok_df` satisfies your criteria

```
Not_OK_df[
    Not_OK_df.apply(
        lambda not_ok_row: max_counts[not_ok_row['type_id']] > not_ok_row['count'] #returns True if there exists a larger count in ok_df with the same type_id 
        if not_ok_row['type_id'] in max_counts else False, #checks to see if your Not_ok_df row's type_id exists in ok_df
        axis=1
    )
]
```

Comment: @Jeff- Yes this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!